# how to get data in sheet2 from sheet1 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets,

```
Sheet1
Column A = Deptname
Column B = Headname
Column C = Username
```

```
Sheet2
Column A = Headname (???)
Column B = Username
Column C = UserID
```

"`Headname`" column in Sheet2 is blank and what I wanted to do is to get "`Headname`" from Sheet1 by using "`Username`".

I have tried to use `VLookup` but it did not work if username in Sheet1 and Sheet2 is not exactly same.

E.G, given two differents Username as shown on below.

- `Username` in Sheet1 is `"Jenny Oh"` and `"Chan Shu Mei"`
- `Username` in Sheet2 is `"ITC - Jenny Ong"` and `"IA: Chan Shu Mei"`

Any ideas whether it can be done? Thankf in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You can access cells in another sheet like this: `=sheet1!B53;`

Comment: An update in case anyone stumbles across this answer: If you're using a name like `sheet1` that has numbers in it, you need to put the name in single quotes (`'sheet1'`).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking "can I have excel match two strings when they're not exactly the same?"

The short answer is "no"

A computer cannot automatically determine that "Jenny Ong" and "ITC - Jenny Ong" are the same person without additional information.

The longer answer is "maybe"

You may be able to do some transformation to one or both of the names so that they are identical. For example, if all the entries in spreadsheet 2 are in the format "something - name" you might be able to use MID and FIND to extract just the name.

I think this formula should return the name of the person in the first record:
=MID(B1,FIND(" - ", B1)+3,9999)