# How can we Vlookup Sheet1 data in sheet2 with partial match Columns C

Tags: vba, excel

Looking VBA macro/Code which can do this simple match/partial match function in Excel spreadsheet.
I have 2 sheets in a excel workbook.
Sheet1 Contains 
ColumnA = First Name 
ColumnB = Last Name
ColumnC = Job Title

Sheet2 Contains
ColumnA = First Name 
ColumnB = Last Name
ColumnC = Job Title
ColumnD = Emails

I want the macro to vlookup/match Sheet1 ColumnA, B, C with Sheet2 ColumnA, B, C
and get Sheet2 ColumnD data into Sheet1 columnD with respective row matched.

Note:
Data could be case sensitive while doing vlookup/match/partial match.
Have to do partial match Sheet1 and Sheet2 "C" Columns with respective rows

Below are attached files sample and results should look after running the macro.

[Sample and results files](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/kDaSw)
I been through these posts but did not find the answer.

[how to get data in sheet2 from sheet1 in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159592/how-to-get-data-in-sheet2-from-sheet1-in-excel)

[How to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2 with a condition in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416214/how-to-copy-data-from-sheet1-to-sheet2-with-a-condition-in-excel)

[merge data with partial match in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617377/merge-data-with-partial-match-in-r)

[Excel VBA - Search for value from sheet1 in sheet2 and update with adjacent value from sheet1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537816/excel-vba-search-for-value-from-sheet1-in-sheet2-and-update-with-adjacent-valu)

Comment: So the Job Titles in Sheet1 may be shorter but never longer than those in Sheet2?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a **FOR loop** to compare the values:

```
Sub CompleteData()

Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow1 'change to 1 if you have no headers
    For y = 2 To lastrow2 'change to 1 if you have no headers
        If ws1.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 1).Value And ws1.Cells(x, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 2).Value And ws1.Cells(x, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 3).Value Then
            ws1.Cells(x, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 4).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: It does not do any "partial match".  It does only exact match. Sometimes, columnb "melvin" will "melvin CPA"
[Samplefile](https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/3Qzf9CoIYz)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()` and filter Sheet2 columns A to C with corresponding value of each Sheet1 row:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompleteData()
    Dim myRng As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set myRng = .Range("A2", .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("C1", .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            For Each cell In myRng
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Offset(, 1).Value
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cell.Offset(, 2).Value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .cells) > 1 Then cell.Offset(, 3).Value = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).cells(1, 4).Value
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```